# Regex match all elements except ones with certain attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Sorry, if this has been asked and answered before, but I cannot seem to find an answer to this.

Since regex is not my strong side I turn to you, SO. I'm stuck with a regex that needs to find all the image tags in text except ones that have a certain attribute and value. At this point I am not even sure if that is doable, if it is - any help is appreciated.

```
/<img.*?\/(img)?>/si
```

This is what I use to match all of the image tags - simple and straight forward. But what should I add/modify for it to *ignore* image tags with `class='ignore'` for example.

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a good match for RegEx, you should use a HTML parser instead.

Comment: Please have a look at the [first question that comes up in the related section](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/112968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/67332)

Find all images in html that have `ignore` class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//img[contains(@class, "ignore")]') as $img) {
    // do something with $img
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```